# # in url getting ignored in php 5.2

Tags: php

I have php 5.2. The # in the URL is getting ignored by PHP. Anyone knows why.

For example if the url is

=">http://localhost?a=b#*=*

I am only seeing a=b

Comment: Future readers might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78132466/17865804) helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#` character has [a special meaning in URLs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3).

```
http://localhost?a=b#test
```

causes the browser to load `http://localhost?a=b` and jump to the element with the `id` or `name` of "test". That part is never sent to the server.

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed it :). But the latest Facebook Connect optionally sends it across in some responses back to the client. Can there be a way for the client to know when it is present?

Comment: side effect of using stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 4):

The URL fragment is not sent to the server by the browser. If you want to include an actual "#" in the query string then you need to encode it as `%23` first.