# How to pass # in url params?

Tags: php, url, hash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [# in url getting ignored in php 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463553/in-url-getting-ignored-in-php-5-2)

I have following link on webpage. Here I am sending **return**(`/profile?id=6#contacts`) as url param to return back after operation complete. But it is sending only `/profile?id=6` to **verify.php** script.

http://example.com/verify.php?id=1&sessionId=6&return=/profile.php?id=6#contacts

I know that hash value is not passed to server but I want to know that is there any way to pass compelete **return** param to server with **#** value.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/urlencode) the entire `return` parameter.